# Is it possible to find the complex roots of $x^3 + 2 x^2 - 3 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

Sorry to ask so many roots questions in such short bursts, but I want to know if it is humanly possible to compute the complex root of

$$x^3 + 2 x^2 - 3  = 0$$

through algebraic manipulation?

Note that it also has a real root if you factor it a little bit

If not possible, please tell me how you can arrive at that conclusion

Thank you!

Comment: If you factor out the real root, you can just use the quadratic equation to find the remaining two roots.

Comment: Two notes:  One, by inspection you can find the real root of 1.   Two, if you want the sledgehammer,  there is a cubic formula.  (And a quartic formula).

Comment: @Alan and the not-nearly-as-complicated-and-cumbersome rational root theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

P.S. Every polynomial of odd degree has at least one real root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note by the Rational Root Theorem that $1$ is a root of the cubic. Proceeding by [polynomial long division](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/polydiv2.htm) gives the factorization
$$(x-1)(x^2+3x+3)$$
You can then use the quadratic formula and find the roots of the second factor.

Comment: Ok so dividing the root youve already found simplifies the original equation => not so obvious. thanks

Answer (score 7):

$x^3+2x^2-3=x^2(x-1)+3(x-1)(x+1)=(x-1)(x^2+3x+3)$.

So,  the roots of the original equation are $x=1$ and the two roots of $x^2+3x+3$.

You can find the roots of $x^2+3x+3$ by using the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 3):

As we see that $x=1$ is a root of the equation, we therefore factor it into $(x-1)(x^2+3x+3)$.
Now, with the quadratic formula, the roots are:
$$\begin{align}
x=&\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\
=&\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{9-12}}{2}\\
=&\frac{-3\pm i\sqrt 3}{2}
\end{align}$$